# how to recognize word pairs in raw_input with python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python and practicing by writing a text based adventure game. I have a large lists of types of candies, some one word long, some two words or more. I have a function that recognizes if the user inputs a one word candy, but it can't recognize the two word candies because the input is split into two words. Is there a way to recognize word pairs? I'm thinking that I could split my list into all one words and then recognize each one and hook them back up, I'm not sure how to do that, or if there would be a better option?

This is my function for recognizing raw_input and checking it against the candy list. The prompt isn't "what kind of candy do you want to buy?" it's "you're in a candy store, now do something" so I expect the input to be complicated.

```
action=raw_input(">")
results=list(action.rsplit())    
inter2 = set(results).intersection(candy_list)
if len(inter2)>0:
    inter_2=list(inter2)
    for x in inter_2:
        inventory.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use a set structure?

Maybe you should use list:

```
candy_list = [...] # your predefined list
inventory = [...] # the inventory
results = raw_input(">")
if results in candy_list:
    inventory.append(results)
```

Comment: sorry, I had the wrong code up there. The prompt isn't "what do you want to buy?" it's "you're in a candy store, do something" So the input will be more complicated than that